# Is there a way to determine the destination URL of a Sendgrid tracking link without triggering a click event in Sendgrid?

Tags: http, redirect, url-rewriting, sendgrid, privacy

As the recipient of a Sendgrid hyperlink I want a method to check where it points which does not cause Sendgrid to register that I have clicked the link.

Sendgrid links are common in marketing emails globally and look like this:  `https://u12345678.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=<undecipherable-string>`

A HTTP HEAD request is intended to not download or modify the requested resource, so I thought this was a good bet. I tried the following (using my Mac terminal),

```
curl -I https://u12345678.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=<undecipherable-string>
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2023 12:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://masked-destination.com/
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
```

This successfully reveals the masked destination - however I established that the click count is in fact incremented by this request. [Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRbiZ.png)

I also established that Sendgrid will consider an unsubscribe link to be "clicked" when a HEAD request is made, thereby unsubscribing the recipient. (Such links have a slightly different url path `wf/unsubscribe?upn=...`)

For context, I am not interested in determining these endpoints as an individual. I am building something to programatically scan emails and check these links automatically with minimal disruption to the participants.

If there is no method to achieve this, I suspect there will be ongoing distortion to Sendgrid click counts and user subscriptions globally, as many email security tools will be checking these destinations indiscriminately (probably via HEAD requests). I would expect Sendgrid to be concerned about this but could not find anything in their documentation suggesting an awareness of this problem.